# Proper way to range over a variable?

Tags: go

I have code that is inside an ever-expanding switch statement. I would like to just make this a loop though. Any idea how I can change this to a loop since this is generally the same code?

```
switch key {
    case types.CREATE_NEW_BUCKETS_INTERVAL_KEY:
        b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval.CorrelationID = correlationID //Notice how this is repeating
        b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval.Task = m[types.TASK]
        b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval.ExecuteTime = executeTime

    case types.BUCKET_SWEEP_KEY:
        b.OngoingBucketSweep.CorrelationID = correlationID
        b.OngoingBucketSweep.Task = m[types.TASK]
        b.OngoingBucketSweep.ExecuteTime = executeTime

    case types.SEND_STATUS_ON_FINISHED_KEY:
        b.OngoingSendStatusOnFished.CorrelationID = correlationID
        b.OngoingSendStatusOnFished.Task = m[types.TASK]
        b.OngoingSendStatusOnFished.ExecuteTime = executeTime

}
```

Is there a way to just loop over the variables?

These are all ScheduledTask types which look like this:

```
type ScheduleTask struct {
    Task             string `json:"task"`
    ExecuteTime      int64  `json:"execute_time"`
    CorrelationID    int64  `json:"correlation_id"`
}
```

Comment: @ThinkGoodly Just updated the post with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to bundle up repeated logic:

```
set := func(t *ScheduleTask) {
    t.CorrelationID = correlationID
    t.Task = m[types.TASK]
    t.ExecuteTime = executeTime

}

switch key {
case types.CREATE_NEW_BUCKETS_INTERVAL_KEY:
    set(&b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval)
case types.BUCKET_SWEEP_KEY:
    set(&b.OngoingBucketSweep)
case types.SEND_STATUS_ON_FINISHED_KEY:
    set(&b.OngoingSendStatusOnFished)
}
```

Another option is to get a pointer to the schedule task and fields using that pointer:

```
var t *ScheduleTask
switch key {
case types.CREATE_NEW_BUCKETS_INTERVAL_KEY:
    t = &b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval
case types.BUCKET_SWEEP_KEY:
    t = &b.OngoingBucketSweep
case types.SEND_STATUS_ON_FINISHED_KEY:
    t = &b.OngoingSendStatusOnFished
}

t.CorrelationID = correlationID
t.Task = m[types.TASK]
t.ExecuteTime = executeTime
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup a container or a map which accepts the key as the key and returns the object that you intend to modify as the value.

For example:

```
var container = map[string]interface{}{
  types.CREATE_NEW_BUCKETS_INTERVAL_KEY : b.OngoingCreateNewBucketsInterval}
```

In your for loop, you can lookup this map to get the object which needs to be modified.

The only ask is, all the values in the map must be implementing the same interface to set correlationId, task and executionTime.